# Unknown argument on mutation

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, typegraphql

I am new to graphql, I am getting below errors for followig mutation, can someone help me what is the reason

- Unknown type "RefundMutationFormInput". Did you mean "RefundFormMutationInput" or "RefundFormMutationElement"?
- Unknown argument "orderNumber" on field "Mutation.refund".
- Unknown argument "bookingItemId" on field "Mutation.refund".

[image]

Comment: Please add more information so we can help you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  For the most part GraphQL doesn't use image files at all.  Can you [edit] the question to include required details in plain text, especially the text of your GraphQL query and a relevant fragment of the corresponding GraphQL schema?

Comment: Please also add the schema, or at least relevant parts of the schema, as code.